# Hibernate Embeddable Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, mapping

I have an object with a field that can be a number of object types. This object is encoded in a single table with a discriminator column for the field's subtypes. Each of these subtypes have their fields mapped to a column in the parent objects table. I cannot seem to model this in hibernate. The code bellow will return null for `getSubfield()` regardless of what subtype data is in the table.

*Schema*

```
  id   type   whosit   whatsit  
+----+------+--------+---------+
| 1  | "A"  | "test" | null    |
| 2  | "B"  | null   | "test"  |
+----+------+--------+---------+
```

*Domain Objects*

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    protected @Id @GeneratedValue int id;
    protected Subfield subfield;

    public Subfield getSubfield() {return subfield;} 
}


@Embeddable
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Subfield {}


@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class TypeA extends Subfield {
    public String whosit;
}


@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class TypeB extends Subfield {
    public String whatsit;
}
```

*"SELECT p FROM parent p"*

```
{id=1,subfield=null}
{id=2,subfield=null}
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I want with this object model, or do I need to get a bit more creative (this is a legacy database, changing the schema is not preferred)

Comment: A colleague at work pointed me to http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1910 . I guess it is not supported =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you can't easily change the schema, but how about adding a couple of views?

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately, it is still a modification to the database structure. I am trying to solve this with code, if nothing else, it seems like something that hibernate could do and I am curious as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: +1 to your comment and reminding SO that sometimes, we can't "make it right" and fix bad schema designs.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

As pointed by the asker, hibernate does not support inheritance of embeddable classes (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1910).

According to the Eclipse wiki, the JPA does not specify this behavior, but EclipseLink does support it (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Inheritance).

My suggestion is to smash the class hierachy entirely inside Subfield. Horrible, but should work until this is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old.

One way around this is as specified above. Create a view. You say you don't want to change the schema. Then don't. You can create a new schema which maps the old schema and does what you want. (Possibly depending on database)